# WSO2 ESB 4.8.1 custom proxy wizard does not start

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

I am using Java 1.8.0_25 on 64-bit Windows 8.1, logged as admin.
When looking into console output I can see the following:
[2014-11-25 15:29:28,047] ERROR - ApplicationDispatcher Servlet.service() for se
rvlet bridgeservlet threw exception

```
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: PWC6033: Error in Javac compilation for JSP

PWC6197: An error occurred at line: 109 in the jsp file: /proxyservices/index.js
p
PWC6199: Generated servlet error:
The type java.lang.CharSequence cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced
from required .class files

PWC6197: An error occurred at line: 109 in the jsp file: /proxyservices/index.js
p
PWC6199: Generated servlet error:
The method replace(char, char) in the type String is not applicable for the argu
ments (String, String)


        at org.apache.jasper.compiler.DefaultErrorHandler.javacError(DefaultErro
rHandler.java:129)
        at org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.javacError(ErrorDispatcher
.java:299)
        at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.generateClass(Compiler.java:392)
        at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:453)
        at org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.compile(JspCompilationContext
.java:625)
        at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper
.java:374)
        at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:4
92)
        at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:378)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:848)
        at org.wso2.carbon.ui.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:155)
        at org.wso2.carbon.ui.TilesJspServlet.service(TilesJspServlet.java:80)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:848)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.http.helper.ContextPathServletAdaptor.service(Con
textPathServletAdaptor.java:37)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ServletRegistration.service
(ServletRegistration.java:61)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ProxyServlet.processAlias(P
roxyServlet.java:128)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ProxyServlet.service(ProxyS
ervlet.java:68)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:848)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.servlet.DelegationServlet.service(Delegati
onServlet.java:68)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(Appl
icationFilterChain.java:305)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationF
ilterChain.java:210)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDisp
atcher.java:749)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doInclude(ApplicationD
ispatcher.java:605)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.include(ApplicationDis
patcher.java:544)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.RequestDispatcherAdaptor.in
clude(RequestDispatcherAdaptor.java:37)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.http.helper.ContextPathServletAdaptor$RequestDisp
atcherAdaptor.include(ContextPathServletAdaptor.java:369)
        at org.apache.jasper.runtime.JspRuntimeLibrary.include(JspRuntimeLibrary
.java:1015)
        at org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.include(PageContextImpl.jav
a:700)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor39.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAcces
sorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
        at org.apache.tiles.jsp.context.JspUtil.doInclude(JspUtil.java:87)
        at org.apache.tiles.jsp.context.JspTilesRequestContext.include(JspTilesR
equestContext.java:88)
        at org.apache.tiles.jsp.context.JspTilesRequestContext.dispatch(JspTiles
RequestContext.java:82)
        at org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.render(BasicTilesContainer.
java:465)
        at org.apache.tiles.jsp.taglib.InsertAttributeTag.render(InsertAttribute
Tag.java:140)
        at org.apache.tiles.jsp.taglib.InsertAttributeTag.render(InsertAttribute
Tag.java:117)
        at org.apache.tiles.jsp.taglib.RenderTagSupport.execute(RenderTagSupport
.java:171)
        at org.apache.tiles.jsp.taglib.RoleSecurityTagSupport.doEndTag(RoleSecur
ityTagSupport.java:75)
        at org.apache.tiles.jsp.taglib.ContainerTagSupport.doEndTag(ContainerTag
Support.java:80)
        at org.apache.jsp.admin.layout.template_jsp._jspx_meth_tiles_insertAttri
bute_7(org.apache.jsp.admin.layout.template_jsp:603)
        at org.apache.jsp.admin.layout.template_jsp._jspService(org.apache.jsp.a
dmin.layout.template_jsp:335)
        at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:111)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:848)
        at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper
.java:403)
        at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:4
92)
        at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:378)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:848)
        at org.wso2.carbon.ui.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:155)
        at org.wso2.carbon.ui.TilesJspServlet.service(TilesJspServlet.java:80)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:848)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.http.helper.ContextPathServletAdaptor.service(Con
textPathServletAdaptor.java:37)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ServletRegistration.service
(ServletRegistration.java:61)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ProxyServlet.processAlias(P
roxyServlet.java:128)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ProxyServlet.service(ProxyS
ervlet.java:68)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:848)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.servlet.DelegationServlet.service(Delegati
onServlet.java:68)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(Appl
icationFilterChain.java:305)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationF
ilterChain.java:210)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDisp
atcher.java:749)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(Applica
tionDispatcher.java:487)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationD
ispatcher.java:412)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDis
patcher.java:339)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.RequestDispatcherAdaptor.fo
rward(RequestDispatcherAdaptor.java:30)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.http.helper.ContextPathServletAdaptor$RequestDisp
atcherAdaptor.forward(ContextPathServletAdaptor.java:362)
        at org.apache.tiles.servlet.context.ServletTilesRequestContext.forward(S
ervletTilesRequestContext.java:198)
        at org.apache.tiles.servlet.context.ServletTilesRequestContext.dispatch(
ServletTilesRequestContext.java:185)
        at org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.render(BasicTilesContainer.
java:419)
        at org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.render(BasicTilesContainer.
java:370)
        at org.wso2.carbon.ui.action.ActionHelper.render(ActionHelper.java:52)
        at org.wso2.carbon.ui.TilesJspServlet.service(TilesJspServlet.java:101)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:848)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.http.helper.ContextPathServletAdaptor.service(Con
textPathServletAdaptor.java:37)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ServletRegistration.service
(ServletRegistration.java:61)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ProxyServlet.processAlias(P
roxyServlet.java:128)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ProxyServlet.service(ProxyS
ervlet.java:68)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:848)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.servlet.DelegationServlet.service(Delegati
onServlet.java:68)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(Appl
icationFilterChain.java:305)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationF
ilterChain.java:210)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.filter.CharacterSetFilter.doFilter(Charact
erSetFilter.java:61)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(Appl
icationFilterChain.java:243)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationF
ilterChain.java:210)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperV
alve.java:222)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextV
alve.java:123)
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(Authentica
torBase.java:472)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.j
ava:171)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.j
ava:99)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CompositeValve.continueInvocation(C
ompositeValve.java:178)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.TomcatValveContainer.invokeValves(T
omcatValveContainer.java:49)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CompositeValve.invoke(CompositeValv
e.java:141)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.inv
oke(CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.java:156)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:
936)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonContextCreatorValve.invoke(Ca
rbonContextCreatorValve.java:52)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineVal
ve.java:118)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.jav
a:407)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp
11Processor.java:1004)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(
AbstractProtocol.java:589)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoin
t.java:1653)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.
java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor
.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
[2014-11-25 15:29:28,562] ERROR - ApplicationDispatcher Servlet.service() for se
rvlet bridgeservlet threw exception
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: PWC6033: Error in Javac compilation for JSP

PWC6197: An error occurred at line: 109 in the jsp file: /proxyservices/index.js
p
PWC6199: Generated servlet error:
The type java.lang.CharSequence cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced
from required .class files

PWC6197: An error occurred at line: 109 in the jsp file: /proxyservices/index.js
p
PWC6199: Generated servlet error:
The method replace(char, char) in the type String is not applicable for the argu
ments (String, String)


        at org.apache.jasper.compiler.DefaultErrorHandler.javacError(DefaultErro
rHandler.java:129)
        at org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.javacError(ErrorDispatcher
.java:299)
        at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.generateClass(Compiler.java:392)
        at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:453)
        at org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.compile(JspCompilationContext
.java:625)
        at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper
.java:374)
        at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:4
92)
        at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:378)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:848)
        at org.wso2.carbon.ui.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:155)
        at org.wso2.carbon.ui.TilesJspServlet.service(TilesJspServlet.java:80)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:848)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.http.helper.ContextPathServletAdaptor.service(Con
textPathServletAdaptor.java:37)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ServletRegistration.service
(ServletRegistration.java:61)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ProxyServlet.processAlias(P
roxyServlet.java:128)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ProxyServlet.service(ProxyS
ervlet.java:68)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:848)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.servlet.DelegationServlet.service(Delegati
onServlet.java:68)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(Appl
icationFilterChain.java:305)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationF
ilterChain.java:210)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDisp
atcher.java:749)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doInclude(ApplicationD
ispatcher.java:605)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.include(ApplicationDis
patcher.java:544)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.RequestDispatcherAdaptor.in
clude(RequestDispatcherAdaptor.java:37)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.http.helper.ContextPathServletAdaptor$RequestDisp
atcherAdaptor.include(ContextPathServletAdaptor.java:369)
        at org.apache.jasper.runtime.JspRuntimeLibrary.include(JspRuntimeLibrary
.java:1015)
        at org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.include(PageContextImpl.jav
a:689)
        at org.apache.tiles.jsp.context.JspUtil.doInclude(JspUtil.java:98)
        at org.apache.tiles.jsp.context.JspTilesRequestContext.include(JspTilesR
equestContext.java:88)
        at org.apache.tiles.jsp.context.JspTilesRequestContext.dispatch(JspTiles
RequestContext.java:82)
        at org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.render(BasicTilesContainer.
java:465)
        at org.apache.tiles.jsp.taglib.InsertAttributeTag.render(InsertAttribute
Tag.java:140)
        at org.apache.tiles.jsp.taglib.InsertAttributeTag.render(InsertAttribute
Tag.java:117)
        at org.apache.tiles.jsp.taglib.RenderTagSupport.execute(RenderTagSupport
.java:171)
        at org.apache.tiles.jsp.taglib.RoleSecurityTagSupport.doEndTag(RoleSecur
ityTagSupport.java:75)
        at org.apache.tiles.jsp.taglib.ContainerTagSupport.doEndTag(ContainerTag
Support.java:80)
        at org.apache.jsp.admin.layout.template_jsp._jspx_meth_tiles_insertAttri
bute_7(org.apache.jsp.admin.layout.template_jsp:603)
        at org.apache.jsp.admin.layout.template_jsp._jspService(org.apache.jsp.a
dmin.layout.template_jsp:335)
        at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:111)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:848)
        at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper
.java:403)
        at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:4
92)
        at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:378)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:848)
        at org.wso2.carbon.ui.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:155)
        at org.wso2.carbon.ui.TilesJspServlet.service(TilesJspServlet.java:80)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:848)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.http.helper.ContextPathServletAdaptor.service(Con
textPathServletAdaptor.java:37)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ServletRegistration.service
(ServletRegistration.java:61)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ProxyServlet.processAlias(P
roxyServlet.java:128)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ProxyServlet.service(ProxyS
ervlet.java:68)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:848)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.servlet.DelegationServlet.service(Delegati
onServlet.java:68)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(Appl
icationFilterChain.java:305)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationF
ilterChain.java:210)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDisp
atcher.java:749)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(Applica
tionDispatcher.java:487)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationD
ispatcher.java:412)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDis
patcher.java:339)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.RequestDispatcherAdaptor.fo
rward(RequestDispatcherAdaptor.java:30)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.http.helper.ContextPathServletAdaptor$RequestDisp
atcherAdaptor.forward(ContextPathServletAdaptor.java:362)
        at org.apache.tiles.servlet.context.ServletTilesRequestContext.forward(S
ervletTilesRequestContext.java:198)
        at org.apache.tiles.servlet.context.ServletTilesRequestContext.dispatch(
ServletTilesRequestContext.java:185)
        at org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.render(BasicTilesContainer.
java:419)
        at org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.render(BasicTilesContainer.
java:370)
        at org.wso2.carbon.ui.action.ActionHelper.render(ActionHelper.java:52)
        at org.wso2.carbon.ui.TilesJspServlet.service(TilesJspServlet.java:101)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:848)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.http.helper.ContextPathServletAdaptor.service(Con
textPathServletAdaptor.java:37)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ServletRegistration.service
(ServletRegistration.java:61)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ProxyServlet.processAlias(P
roxyServlet.java:128)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ProxyServlet.service(ProxyS
ervlet.java:68)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:848)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.servlet.DelegationServlet.service(Delegati
onServlet.java:68)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(Appl
icationFilterChain.java:305)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationF
ilterChain.java:210)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.filter.CharacterSetFilter.doFilter(Charact
erSetFilter.java:61)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(Appl
icationFilterChain.java:243)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationF
ilterChain.java:210)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperV
alve.java:222)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextV
alve.java:123)
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(Authentica
torBase.java:472)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.j
ava:171)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.j
ava:99)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CompositeValve.continueInvocation(C
ompositeValve.java:178)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.TomcatValveContainer.invokeValves(T
omcatValveContainer.java:49)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CompositeValve.invoke(CompositeValv
e.java:141)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.inv
oke(CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.java:156)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:
936)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonContextCreatorValve.invoke(Ca
rbonContextCreatorValve.java:52)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineVal
ve.java:118)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.jav
a:407)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp
11Processor.java:1004)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(
AbstractProtocol.java:589)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoin
t.java:1653)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.
java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor
.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
[2014-11-25 15:29:28,607] ERROR - JspTilesRequestContext JSPException while incl
uding path '/proxyservices/index.jsp'.
javax.servlet.jsp.JspException: ServletException while including page.
        at org.apache.tiles.jsp.context.JspUtil.doInclude(JspUtil.java:102)
        at org.apache.tiles.jsp.context.JspTilesRequestContext.include(JspTilesR
equestContext.java:88)
        at org.apache.tiles.jsp.context.JspTilesRequestContext.dispatch(JspTiles
RequestContext.java:82)
        at org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.render(BasicTilesContainer.
java:465)
        at org.apache.tiles.jsp.taglib.InsertAttributeTag.render(InsertAttribute
Tag.java:140)
        at org.apache.tiles.jsp.taglib.InsertAttributeTag.render(InsertAttribute
Tag.java:117)
        at org.apache.tiles.jsp.taglib.RenderTagSupport.execute(RenderTagSupport
.java:171)
        at org.apache.tiles.jsp.taglib.RoleSecurityTagSupport.doEndTag(RoleSecur
ityTagSupport.java:75)
        at org.apache.tiles.jsp.taglib.ContainerTagSupport.doEndTag(ContainerTag
Support.java:80)
        at org.apache.jsp.admin.layout.template_jsp._jspx_meth_tiles_insertAttri
bute_7(org.apache.jsp.admin.layout.template_jsp:603)
        at org.apache.jsp.admin.layout.template_jsp._jspService(org.apache.jsp.a
dmin.layout.template_jsp:335)
        at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:111)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:848)
        at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper
.java:403)
        at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:4
92)
        at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:378)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:848)
        at org.wso2.carbon.ui.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:155)
        at org.wso2.carbon.ui.TilesJspServlet.service(TilesJspServlet.java:80)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:848)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.http.helper.ContextPathServletAdaptor.service(Con
textPathServletAdaptor.java:37)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ServletRegistration.service
(ServletRegistration.java:61)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ProxyServlet.processAlias(P
roxyServlet.java:128)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ProxyServlet.service(ProxyS
ervlet.java:68)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:848)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.servlet.DelegationServlet.service(Delegati
onServlet.java:68)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(Appl
icationFilterChain.java:305)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationF
ilterChain.java:210)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDisp
atcher.java:749)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(Applica
tionDispatcher.java:487)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationD
ispatcher.java:412)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDis
patcher.java:339)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.RequestDispatcherAdaptor.fo
rward(RequestDispatcherAdaptor.java:30)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.http.helper.ContextPathServletAdaptor$RequestDisp
atcherAdaptor.forward(ContextPathServletAdaptor.java:362)
        at org.apache.tiles.servlet.context.ServletTilesRequestContext.forward(S
ervletTilesRequestContext.java:198)
        at org.apache.tiles.servlet.context.ServletTilesRequestContext.dispatch(
ServletTilesRequestContext.java:185)
        at org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.render(BasicTilesContainer.
java:419)
        at org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.render(BasicTilesContainer.
java:370)
        at org.wso2.carbon.ui.action.ActionHelper.render(ActionHelper.java:52)
        at org.wso2.carbon.ui.TilesJspServlet.service(TilesJspServlet.java:101)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:848)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.http.helper.ContextPathServletAdaptor.service(Con
textPathServletAdaptor.java:37)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ServletRegistration.service
(ServletRegistration.java:61)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ProxyServlet.processAlias(P
roxyServlet.java:128)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ProxyServlet.service(ProxyS
ervlet.java:68)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:848)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.servlet.DelegationServlet.service(Delegati
onServlet.java:68)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(Appl
icationFilterChain.java:305)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationF
ilterChain.java:210)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.filter.CharacterSetFilter.doFilter(Charact
erSetFilter.java:61)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(Appl
icationFilterChain.java:243)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationF
ilterChain.java:210)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperV
alve.java:222)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextV
alve.java:123)
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(Authentica
torBase.java:472)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.j
ava:171)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.j
ava:99)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CompositeValve.continueInvocation(C
ompositeValve.java:178)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.TomcatValveContainer.invokeValves(T
omcatValveContainer.java:49)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CompositeValve.invoke(CompositeValv
e.java:141)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.inv
oke(CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.java:156)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:
936)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonContextCreatorValve.invoke(Ca
rbonContextCreatorValve.java:52)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineVal
ve.java:118)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.jav
a:407)




    ... and more
```

Any ideas how to make it work?

Answer (score 0):

Java 8 is not supported by WSO2 products yet. Please use [Oracle Java 7 (JDK)](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index-jsp-138363.html#JDK7) to run WSO2 products.

For more information, see https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB481/Installation+Prerequisites